# dtale show in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I am exploring this new `Python` package named `dtale`. It is very convenient for `pandas` data frames visualization.

https://pypi.org/project/dtale/

It worked once after 2 hours of loading.

Here is a reproduction of the code, where I reduce the dataset. It still takes hours to load on Jupyter Notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import dtale
table = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns = ['a','b'])
d = dtale.show(table)
d
```

Comments from @cup and @AMC suggested to use it outside Jupyter notebook which I did using python console. It worked fine.

Any ideas on what is taking so long between Jupyter Notebook and Dtale?

Edit: 
It is not realy taking so long. The process block jupyter notebook while the data is accessible through the local link. 
http://LT0PAR01056937:40000/dtale/main/1
Jupyter notebook doesn't print the link and I can't kill it, I need to kill the entire kernel.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using it without Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I just tried this on Google Colab and it worked fine.

Comment: @cup and @ AMC thanks. I used python console on Anaconda prompt. It worked smoothly. I will edit the post to ask clearly about jupyter

Answer (score 2):

I'm the main developer on D-Tale.  So I wonder if the D-Tale is not showing up within your notebook because it is being hosted from HTTPS but the D-TAle process is hosted from HTTP (which will cause a CORS exception)

Also, if you want to kill a D-tale process within your notebook without having the restart the notebook's kernel you can do the following.

```
dtale.instances()
# using any of the data ids that are printed from the previous command
# it will also print the URL of each piece of data you've loaded into D-Tale
dtale.get_instance([data_id]).kill()
```

Also, if your notebook isn't being served under HTTPS you can also try forcing the host to 'localhost' by using the following:

```
dtale.show(df, host='localhost')
```

Then maybe it can be reached from localhost.  You can also try just killing the cell you kicked your D-tale process off from before having to kill the entire kernel.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, using `host='localhost'` resolved the new issue I started seeing, where it said "<machine name> unable to connect". Out of curiosity, why doesn't it default to localhost, similar to jupyter, etc?

Comment: I'm trying to run it from a remote host in a notebook I'm running following the instructions here https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/remote-jupyter-notebook/. I tried the host='localhost' trick but it didn't work... Any other ideas? Do I need to open a separate port or something?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use in Google COlab then this code will help.

```
import pandas as pd
import dtale
import dtale.app as dtale_app

dtale_app.USE_COLAB = True 
dtale.show(pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was getting the same error & couldn't open the link generated by dtale.show(dataset). This answer fixed the issue in my google colab file.

Answer (score 0):

In google colab, adding `import dtale.app as dtale_app` works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import dtale
import dtale.app as dtale_app

table = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns = ['a','b'])
d = dtale.show(table)
d
```